# Programmatic swift: TableView inside a TableView

Tags: swift

I'm currently trying to put a tableview inside a tableview, but programmatically (in order to understand better wtf I'm doing in the storyboard way of doing this). I'm currently stuck at showing the inner table, any help please?

```
class ContactsViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, 
 UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

private let contacts = ContactAPI.getData()
let contactsTableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(contactsTableView)
    contactsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // enable Auto-Layout
    
    contactsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contactsTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    contactsTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    contactsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    contactsTableView.dataSource = self
    contactsTableView.delegate = self 
    
    contactsTableView.register(ContactsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "contactCell")
    contactsTableView.rowHeight = 1000
    contactsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.contacts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsCell
    
    cell.jobLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].jobTitle
    cell.nameLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].name
    
    return cell
}

}
```

The external TableViewCell is given by

```
class ContactsCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    contentView.addSubview(image)
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(jobLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(tablello)
    
   
  }

  // working code that defines image, nameLabel, jobLabel
  let tablello: UITableView = {
   
    let tab = UITableView()
    let data = innerTable()
    
    tab.dataSource = data
    tab.delegate = data
    tab.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
    
    tab.register(gInnerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "gennaroCell")
    tab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return tab
     }()
    }
```

And relative classes

```
class innerTable: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "gennaroCell", for: indexPath) as! gInnerCell
    cell.labelloNapoli.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    print("AO GENNà")
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print("loaded inner")
}



}



class gInnerCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    
    
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    contentView.addSubview(labelloNapoli)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

let labelloNapoli:UILabel = {
    let lable = UILabel()
    lable.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
    return lable
}()
}
```

I've tried turning tablello into a separate View, and adding there the table as a subview, but (although it printed the inside print() ) it messes up all my UI.

Comment: Avoid nested tableview if possible.

Comment: @SPatel is this tip also for gridcollection + tableview nesting?

Comment: Yeah in general avoid nested scrollview

Answer (score 0):

In general what are you trying to accomplish by putting a `tableView` inside of another `tableView`? Are you able to display the same information using a custom `tableViewCell`? Or better yet use a `CollectionView` as they are very flexible when it comes to UI. Sorry for not answering the question; Just trying to get a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish UI wise.

Comment: I should be able to scroll vertically and horizontally : in the only column I'd have "image galleries" i'd be able to scroll in the row to show multiple images